# Android Contact Picker

Tags: android-contacts

I was wondering:

Is it possible to customize the Android Contact Picker so that it can also allow adding a new contact as a menu option in the default contact list?

At the moment, if I invoke the contact picker from my activity, it only displays the default contact list.  I would also like the user to be able to create a new contact if it did not exist already. I have searched this quite a lot but do not find appropriate API to do this. There is nothing in `ContactContract` as far as I can see.

---

Any inputs will be appreciated. I have an HTC sensation where in the messaging app while composing SMS,  the contact picker that pops up has a search bar, the contact list and in the option menu, you have option to add new contact. How is this achieved?

Comment: try out https://github.com/shahbazhashmi/contact-picker

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, no, it's not possible.  This is because the Android contacts framework considers adding and picking as logically distinct operations which should be initiated with different intents.  If you start the contacts picker with the intent `Intent.ACTION_PICK` you'll see a picker-specific version of the contacts UI with everything taken out (e.g. adding or deleting contacts) which isn't relevant for this action.

To see why it's not possible, look in the code for the stock contacts app, in `ContactsListActivity`.  Depending which intent launched the activity, it might be in one of several "modes" defined within the code which govern how the UI presents itself and what behavior is allowed.  If you look in the activity's onCreate() method you'll see this:

(N.B. I'm looking at the Android 2.3.7 source at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com))

```
mMode = MODE_UNKNOWN;
if (UI.LIST_DEFAULT.equals(action) || UI.FILTER_CONTACTS_ACTION.equals(action)) {
    mMode = MODE_DEFAULT;
[...]

} else if (Intent.ACTION_PICK.equals(action)) {
   // XXX These should be showing the data from the URI given in
   // the Intent.
   final String type = intent.resolveType(this);
   if (Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE.equals(type)) {
      mMode = MODE_PICK_CONTACT;
   }
[...]
```

So we see with the intent `Intent.ACTION_PICK` the UI is being put into "picker" mode.  Then further down you see:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

  // If Contacts was invoked by another Activity simply as a way of
  // picking a contact, don't show the options menu
  if ((mMode & MODE_MASK_PICKER) == MODE_MASK_PICKER) {
       return false;
  }

  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
  return true;
}
```

That's why there's no options menu when you launch the contact picker -- the UI is choosing to present itself in a certain way because of the supposed intention you had in launching the picker, i.e. to pick only.

If what you want to do is add a contact you need to launch Contacts with a different intent, in particular `Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT`.  (In onCreate() you will see a section similar to the above in which the activity's mode is set to an "add/edit" value if this intent is received.)